"Session has been closed" Error in solving Maxcut problem by QAOA
I am trying to run this code- https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/quantum-approximate-optimization-algorithm  same way as they mentioned. After running this code, my qiskit Dashboard show 10-12 jobs solved successfully but after that it throws me an Error "Session has been closed" before optimization terminates successfully.
Is there any suggestion about this and how can I can my code on real quantum hardware so that it converges successfully.
